# Is there a difference between "I would love you to come" and "I would love for you to come"?

Tags: phrases

Is there a difference between:
"I would love you to come" and 
"I would love for you to come"?

Comment: Try researching this at [M-W Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/love). (2**love** [v] 3) I'll add that the second variant sounds perhaps a little too effusive to my UK ears.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would say not so much *effusive* as not in the general UK received style-guide. I wouldn't be surprised to hear a Geordie say it, but couldn't imagine the Queen using it.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm more comfortable with the former but my Marketing Manager favoured the latter.

Answer (score 2):

The second form is common in American English and wouldn't be commonly used in (for example) the UK. Beyond that I believe they have the same meaning, sense and emphasis.